# Why is this data type acting weird?

Tags: c, int, printf

Why does the first `printf()` just return the value -536870912 and the second return the difference between the maximum value of an `unsigned int` with the result of multiplying 65535 * 65535. (Running a 64 bit machine).

```
int x = 7 * 536870912;

printf("%d\n", x);// 536,870,912
//answer: 3,758,096,384 - 3 Billion
//returns : - 536870912

printf("%d\n", 65535 * 65535 );// 65,535
// answer : 4,294,836,225 4 Billion
// returns: -131071
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures/images of code — include the code in the question.

Comment: Perhaps you're using a system where `INT_MAX` is less than 3,758,096,384?  I'd guess it's 2³¹-1 and two's complement is overflowing in the usual way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, even on 64-bit systems, the `int` type is still a signed 32-bit type. You could have easily verified it by printing `sizeof(int)`. If you want more then use `long long` which is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits.

Be careful with `long`, it might be 64 bits or it might be only 32 bits. Use `long long`.

Comment: Yeah, that I know about long long which will provide me more storage but if we see (2^32) - 1 = 4294967295 and 7 * 536870912 = 3758096384 and 3758096384< 4294967295 , then why it is happening?

Comment: @Adam You forget the *signed* part, which *halves* the max number to around 2 billion (with a low of minus 2 billion). That's because one bit is used for sign.

Comment: Thanks for the help, though. :D @Some programmer dude

Comment: But I have one more doubt, why such specific value in case of overflow?

Comment: @Adam Overflowing signed integer is actually [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). However, considering that most systems uses [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) you can easily see the bit-pattern of the expected value, and work out what negative number that will be.